# How to (generically) count duplicate rows (and remove duplicates)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

Is there a generic SELECT statement to detect duplicate rows ("identical", where all columns are equal)? E.G, columns 2 & 4 in the following table

```
 titel                             | interpret        | jahr
-----------------------------------+------------------+-----
 Beauty                            | Ryuichi Sakamoto | 1990
 Goodbye Country (Hello Nightclub) | Groove Armada    | 2001
 Glee                              | Bran Van 3000    | 1997
 Goodbye Country (Hello  Nightclub)| Groove Armada    | 2001
```

Or do I need a SELECT which is specific to the table?

Someone has given me an Sqlite d/b with multiple tables each of which look like like they have multiple identical rows (with different columns in each table), so I would prefer a generic solution.

After that, I have to figure out how to delete the duplicates. Maybe I can use DISTINCT on the SELECT, store in a temp table, delete the original and rename the temp table?

Comment: +1 Thanks, but Sqlite says "a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right idea all along. You will have to run the following on each table:

```
select distinct titel, interpret, jahr from table1
```

You could dump the distinct rows into another table like so:

```
create table table2 as
select distinct titel, interpret, jahr from table1
```

You can then drop the intial table like so:

```
drop table table1
```

Rename the newly created table to table1 like so:

```
alter table table2 rename to table1
```

To find row number of each record in the table:

```
select a.rowid, a.* from table1 a
```

To find row number of only the records that are duplicate:

```
select a.rowid, a.* 
from table1 a 
inner join 
(
      select titel, interpret, jahr 
      from table1 
      group by titel, interpret, jahr 
      having count(*) > 1
) b on 
      a.titel = b.titel 
      and a.interpret = b.interpret 
      and a.jahr = b.jahr
```

Comment: Actually, I have probably asked two questions here. My bad. First I want to show the guy how gave me the d/b just how bad it is, then I need to clean up his mess. Sorry about that - should I edit the question & post another, so as to have two?

Comment: @user814064 I am sorry that neither of the queries above will return only 2nd and 4th. Your query in comments of group by...having will return just those records that are duplicate

Comment: @Mawg no worries. To show only those records that are duplicate, use the SQL containing `group by...having` in user814064's comment under your question

Comment: @Mawg seems like I cannot see user814064's comment; perhaps it was removed. SQL to show only those records that are duplicated is `select titel, interpret, jahr, count(*) from table1 group by titel, interpret, jahr having count(*) > 1`

Comment: +1 Thanks. Can I be cheeky and ask how I would get the value of the duplicated row? Where would I put DISTINCT?

Comment: @Mawg That's a two part question, so I will try to answer them in two comments. First about getting value of duplicate row - Are you wanting to get the row number of the duplicated row? For example: 1 is Beauty, 2 is Goodbye, 3 is Glee, 4 is Goodbye etc.? If that's the case, you could do `select rowid, titel, interpret, jahr from table2`.

Comment: I have updated the answer to also include row numbers for duplicate rows. For the 2nd part of the question - where would you put distinct: You would put distinct immediately after `select` statement as in: `select distinct column1, column2, column3 from table` to get only distinct rows

Comment: You are giving too much help. I have awarded you the answer and started a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680809/my-table-contains-duplicate-rows-how-to-show-one