# My table contains duplicate rows, how to show one?

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

Further to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680531/how-to-generically-count-duplicate-rows-and-remove-duplicates), this table (expanded from the last question) contains duplicate rows

```
 titel                             | interpret        | jahr
-----------------------------------+------------------+-----
 Beauty                            | Ryuichi Sakamoto | 1990
 Goodbye Country (Hello Nightclub) | Groove Armada    | 2001
 Glee                              | Bran Van 3000    | 1997
 Glee                              | Bran Van 3000    | 1997
 Beauty                            | Ryuichi Sakamoto | 1990
 Goodbye Country (Hello  Nightclub)| Groove Armada    | 2001
 Glee                              | Groove Armada    | 2001
```

how would I SELECT to get one example of each set of duplicate rows?  (the final row consists entirely of duplicate columns, but is not a duplicate row).

I.E, the result would return

```
| Beauty                            | Ryuichi Sakamoto | 1990
| Goodbye Country (Hello Nightclub) | Groove Armada    | 2001
| Glee                              | Bran Van 3000    | 1997
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
select distinct titel, interpret, jahr from tablename
```

To get the edited result, you could do something rather interesting like this:

```
select * 
from table1 
where rowid in 
(
    -- get the first row of each distinct titel
    select min(sr) 
    from 
    (select distinct titel from table1) a 
    inner join 
    (
        -- get first row number for each distinct titel/interpret/jahr
        select min(rowid) as sr, titel, interpret, jahr 
        from table1 
        group by titel, interpret, jahr
    ) b 
        on a.titel = b.titel 
    group by 
        a.titel
);
```

Results would look like this:

```
titel                            |interpret       |jahr
Beauty                           |Ryuichi Sakamoto|1990
Goodbye Country (Hello Nightclub)|Groove Armada   |2001
Glee                             |Bran Van 3000   |1997
```

Comment: Are you sure that that would give distinct rows? E.G, in the now updated question, what would it say about the new final row? Duplicate or not? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mawg It filters out rows that are complete duplicates. If any of the columns are different, it will show both rows. So it will show two rows for `Glee`: 1997 and 2001.

Comment: Oh I see the edit. I am sorry. My query will result in 2 records for glee - one with interpret=Bran Van 3000/jahr=1997 and one with interpret=Groove Armada/jahr=2001. The database will look at all columns when determining if it is duplicate or not. Do you want just Glee with Bran Van 3000?

Comment: I want to SELCT rows which are one to one identical - which every column of one row equal to every column of another row, and I want to show just one of those rows.  In the table there are 4 distinct rows; 3 of them have duplicate rows

Comment: @Mawg you are correct - 4 rows are distinct. 3 titels have duplicate rows. My latest longer query should give you the results you need; you will get one row for Beauty, one for Goodbye Country and one for Glee. Is it not giving you the result you want? If so, let me know and I can certain review